# How do I run a scala application using gradle?

Tags: scala, gradle

I added the scala plugin to gradle, but i don't how to run it. There's no run task when i create a scala project.

How do I run the scala project?

My gradle build script:

```
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'scala'
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.13.1'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the classpath as well. Change run task declaration to:

```
task run(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
   main = 'Demo'
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

And it will work fine. [Demo](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/39216287).